# Indexing for keyset pagination in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, innodb

I am trying to build an index in mysql to support a keyset pagination query. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM invoice 
  WHERE company_id = 'someguid' 
    AND id > 'lastguidfromlastpage' 
  ORDER BY id
  LIMIT 10
```

Common knowledge on this says an index on `company_id` would contain the PRIMARY KEY of the table (`id`). Because of this I would expect to be able to use rows directly from the index without any need for the query to sort results first however my explain plan shows a filesort and an index merge:

```
mysql> explain SELECT *
-> FROM invoice
-> WHERE company_id = '37687714-2e9d-4daa-aee6-f7d56962f903'
->   AND id > '525ae038-0cc3-4f9a-85e6-6f36d43fae40'
-> ORDER BY id
-> LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type        | possible_keys               | key                         | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                                                     |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | invoice | NULL       | index_merge | PRIMARY,invoice__company_id | invoice__company_id,PRIMARY | 76,38   | NULL |   48 |   100.00 | Using intersect(invoice__company_id,PRIMARY); Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

If I explicitly add the id to the index then I get the explain plan I would expect:

```
mysql> explain SELECT *
    -> FROM invoice
    -> WHERE company_id = '37687714-2e9d-4daa-aee6-f7d56962f903'
    ->   AND id > '525ae038-0cc3-4f9a-85e6-6f36d43fae40'
    -> ORDER BY id
    -> LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys                  | key                            | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | invoice | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,invoice__company_id_id | invoice__company_id_id,PRIMARY | 76      | NULL |   98 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `invoice_number` varchar(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `identifier` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_by` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_source` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `invoice__company_id_id` (`company_id`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

select @@optimizer_switch;

```
use_index_extensions=on
```

MySQL version:

- version: 5.7.26-29-57-log
- innodb_version: 5.7.26-29
- version_comment: Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel29, Revision 03540a3, WSREP version 31.37, wsrep_31.37

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

There are a few sources explaining that the company_id index on it's own should be sufficient for this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30152513/64023
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/136029/166838

I've been unable to find official documentation about exactly what to expect. Is this related to the datatypes for the id? Is the common knowledge about mysql+innodb behavior incorrect?

Comment: This manual page may be what you're looking for: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-extensions.html Note this only applies to MySQL 5.6 and later. If you use an older version of MySQL, index extension optimization is not implemented.

Comment: Could you add the output of ´SHOW CREATE TABLE invoice´?

Comment: @jkavalik yep, done. Sorry, I meant to post that...

Comment: what is the mysql version?

Comment: you could do `select @@optimizer_switch;` and check if `use_index_extensions` is in there?

Comment: @jkavalik done, use_index_extensions is there.

Comment: @Michael it should work as far as I know, but I already reported one bug (MariaDB though) where the optimizer picks nonsensical index_merge (like yours, merging already present column) so I think it is similar optimizer hickup - you could try to just disable index_merge or use `ignore index(PRIMARY)` to see that the original index is able to work the same way the manually extended one does. Hard to say what triggers it, might be statistics of those UUID, might be the varchar itself (any reason not to use fixed-size char?)

Comment: I'd believe optimizer hickup, the first query without the `>` does have a sensible plan. There is no great reason for varchar except for history and over-vigilance in converting everything to utf8mb4, guids and then deciding varchar is a good pattern there.

Comment: @BillKarwin thank you, those docs are very helpful, after reading that I'm pretty convinced that I'm hitting an optimizer quirk/bug

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`  Preferably do it from the same client that is performing the `SELECT`.

Comment: Please show us the declaration of `invoice__company_id_id`.

Comment: @RickJames updated.

Comment: `1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)` -- Run the `EXPLAIN` again and immediately follow it by `SHOW WARNINGS;`.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem before.  Here is my analysis of it.

- It occurs in MySQL 5.7 and 8.0, but apparently not in older versions and not in MariaDB.
- The "solution" I prefer is to change the indexes thus:

  ```
     INDEX(company_id)      -- DROP this
     INDEX(company_id, id)  -- ADD this
  ```

Although the 2-column index is theoretically identical to the one-column index for InnoDB (assuming `id` is the PK`), the Optimizer seems to ignore this fact *in some situations*.

Also, I like to explicitly add the PK *when I see a need*.  This signals future readers of the schema (including myself) that some query benefits from the PK being appended.

I have yet to find a case where "index merge intersect" is faster than an equivalent composite index.

I dislike ever using index "hints" for fear that the data distribution will change in the future and my "hint" will make things worse.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work.

For keyset pagination to take effect, you need to have autoincrement integer as your primary id/key. Right now you are using VARCHAR and store UIDs.

Your query won't select "next" UID "larger than"  (`... AND id > '525ae038-0cc3-4f9a-85e6-6f36d43fae40' ...` ).

When you change primary ID to be number, then, this will work.
If you still have issues with indexes, you can try forcing mysql to use your index:

```
SELECT * FROM invoice USE INDEX (invoice__company_id_id)
  WHERE company_id = 'someguid' 
    AND id > 12345 
  ORDER BY id
  LIMIT 10
```